# Itextsharp created PDF file

Tags: asp.net, itext

I used itextsharp library to generate and fill PDF files however; the issue i am having is when you open some of these files in Chrome i get the image below but it does work perfectly fine in IE
[image]

Comment: I think it's a content type error related.. You need to use application/pdf to return the valid content type.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by using application/pdf because i already specified the file type. there has to be something i am missing here or something to do with Chrome...

Comment: Ok, you specified the content-type of the response like this : Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Comment: Yes i already did see below.
                  if (strExt[strExt.Length-1] == "pdf")
                        {
                      Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        }
                         
                 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + objectreader["document"]);
                    Response.Buffer = true;                  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
          
                 Response.BinaryWrite(pdfbytes);

Comment: You need to put this : Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.TransmitFile(pathtofile);

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer, it turned out that when i save the file to the Db i did not add the .pdf as an extension to the file that's why it was coming like that. 
because the form data is saved first then retrieved later.
Thanks for the replies.